# when I update a field of a model, all the other fields are deleted

Tags: python, django

if I update f1, f2 is deleted and if update f2, f1 is deleted ...
how do i keep varying the fields that are not changed?

sorry for my horrible English

views.py

```
def edit_iscrizioni(request, corso_id):
    corsi = Corso.objects.filter( pk=corso_id)
    fasca = Corso.objects.get( pk=corso_id)
    tabella= Iscrizione.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    iscrizione=get_object_or_404(Iscrizione, pk=tabella)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = IscrizioneForm(request.POST, instance= iscrizione)
        if form.is_valid():
            iscrizione = form.save(commit=False)
            iscrizione.user = request.user
            iscrizione.published_date = timezone.now()
            if fasca.progressivo:
                if fasca.f1:
                    iscrizione.corso1_id= corso_id
                if fasca.f2:
                    iscrizione.corso2_id= corso_id

            form.save()


        return redirect('privata')

    else:
        form = IscrizioneForm(instance= iscrizione)
    return render(request, 'corsi/edit.html', {'form':form, 'corsi':corsi})
```

model.py

```
class Corso(models.Model):
    titolo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    progressivo= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    f1= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    f2= models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Iscrizione(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    corso1= models.ForeignKey('Corso', blank=True, null=True, related_name="corso1")
    corso2= models.ForeignKey('Corso', blank=True, null=True, related_name="corso2")
```

Comment: please format your code and update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created an object here:

```
iscrizione = form.save(commit=False)
```

and you should save IT into database - use

```
iscrizione.save()
```

instead of

```
form.save()
```

EDIT
Ok then, i think think something wrong here too:

```
tabella= Iscrizione.objects.filter(user=request.user)
iscrizione=get_object_or_404(Iscrizione, pk=tabella)
```

`tabella` - is a queryset (list of Iscrizione objects), i dont think you can get an object with `pk` (primary key) is equal to queryset.

EDIT

and try

```
        if fasca.progressivo:
            if fasca.f1:
                iscrizione.corso1 = fasca
            if fasca.f2:
                iscrizione.corso2 = fasca
```

Comment: unfortunately I still have the same problem